# Sum of Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We let $m_{I}$ be the Lebesgue-measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$
restricted to the interval $I=(0,1)$ which means $m_{I}=m((0,1)\cap A), A\in\mathcal{B}$. We assume that is proved that $m_{I}$ is a measure.

Now we define the measure $\mu=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}m_I$. Then I have to find a expression for $\mu(A)$.

I think we get:
$$\mu(A)=\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }m_{I}=0 \\
\infty, & \text{if }m_{I}>0
\end{cases}$$
because if $m_{I}=0$ then we got a sum over $0$ and it is just $0$. And if $m_{I}>0$ then we got a sum over a interval (because we have a Lebesgue measure we got a positive number), and then we get that $\mu(A)=\infty$ if $m_{I}>0$. I think the expression for $\mu(A)$ is correct, but I'm not sure how to "prove" it? Can anyone help me?
I have only used intuitive thoughts but how will you show it?

Comment: The convention is that if $x_s\ge 0$ for every $s\in S$ and $S$ is infinite then $\sum_{s\in S}x_s=\sup \{\sum_{s\in T}x_s: T\in [S]^{<\omega}\}$ where $[S]^{<\omega}$ is the set of all finite subsets of $S$. ( I have also sneaked in another convention: That the sum of the members of $\emptyset$ is $ 0.$ Thus when $T=\emptyset$ then $\sum_{s\in T}x_s=0.$)

Answer (score 2):

This does not require any Measure Theory. If $a \geq 0$ and $a_n=a$ for all $n$ then $\sum a_n =\infty$ if $a>0$ and $0$ if $a=0$. To prove this just calculate the partial sums and take the limit.

Comment: +1 This makes me wonder if the underlying question is slightly different.  Why consider $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}m_I$?

Comment: I see!! But my thought about the interval $(a,b)$, $b>a$ was just something I thought, and I have abused some notation so I have deleted it again. Yeah I see that this not require any Measure Theory, but in this problem I also have to show that $\mu$ is sum-finite. Can you please write it up, Kavi?. I think I got your point but I find it difficult to write it up formally